# Instagram API using Facebook Graph Permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to develop a simple platform for instagram insights using the new Facebook Graph Instagram API and can't get the right permissions to access my instagram business page. My current setup has my instagram business page connected to my facebook business page with a shared ad account for both.

When I make this request to grab the instagram business page id from the facebook business page using the Graph API Explorer (seen in the documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/instagram-api/page)):

```
/v2.10/{facebook_page_id}?fields=instagram_business_account
```

I get the error:

```
{
  "error": {
     "message": "(#100) No permission to access the Instagram account",
     "type": "OAuthException",
     "code": 100,
     "fbtrace_id": "CU9oNYEt2+q"
  }
}
```

The [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/instagram-api/v2.10) references the need for one of these permissions:

- instagram_basic
- instagram_manage_comments (optional)
- instagram_manage_insights (optional)

However there are no options in the Graph explorer for any of these permissions (see photo below). Boiled down my questions is how do I authenticate my app so that I have permission to get instagram insights from my instagram business page?

[image: Graph explorer sans insta]

Comment: You use Facebook login.

Comment: @WizKid [This](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/overview) documentation for facebook login permissions doesn't have any mention of the instagram_basic, instagram_manage_comments, or instagram_manage_insights and when they are coded in as a string an invalid scope error is thrown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this API is publicly available just yet, looks like you need to be a FB Marketing or Instagram Partner: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/118963648734367/

https://business.instagram.com/blog/new-instagram-api-features/

Comment: Unfortunately this is what the answer that I also came to. Will update my answer when the api is publicly available